# Excel/OOCalc: finding rows that have matching values in one field but different values in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

I have a large table (20-30 cols, 10-15K rows). What I need to do is to find the number of rows that match identically in one (or two) particular field(s), but not in another specific field (rest of the fields are irrelevant). Additionally I would like to be able to use conditional formatting to highlight such rows. Is this possible to do without scripting?

Example table with 10 rows and 4 cols:

```
2.558658418     106.47  STSGGTAALGCLVK      P01857 
2.558658418     106.47  STSGGTAALGCLVK      P01860   <--
2.4505791896    106.4   LYHSEAFTVNFGDTEEAK  P01009
1.3850997023    106.34  EQADFAIEALAK        P35579
1.3850997023    106.34  EQADFALEALAK        Q7Z406      
0.6654422739    105.36  RFDEILEASDGIMVAR    P14618-2
2.0767656337    105.26  STSESTAALGCLVK      P01859
2.0767656337    105.26  STSESTAALGCLVK      P01859
2.0767656337    105.26  STSESTAALGCLVK      P01861   <--
2.0767656337    105.26  STSESTAALGCLVK      P01861
```

What I would like in this scenario is to get the count to be 8 and if possible to have the rows I marked with arrows (for the sake of having an example) to be highlighted. Note that if both the third and the fourth fields are identical (i.e. if the difference between the rows are elsewhere in the table) it's *not* a row of interest.

I don't normally work with Excel/OOCalc so I feel a little out of place working with such tables. I came across some how-tos/forums [one of which](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17900) contains the suggestion of using `COUNTIFS` (e.g. `=COUNTIFS(C2:C114, "YES", F2:F114, "> 0")`) or the OOCalc equivalent with `SUMPRODUCT` (e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C114="YES" ; F2:F114>0)`

The problem with that approach is that it matches the cell contents to a predefined value like `"YES"`. In my case I would like to compare the cell contents to the contents of the cell immediately above/below. Is it possible to tweak the above formulas to fit to my case?

Answer (score 0):

One way to mark the duplicates (it looks like that that is what you are after) is to put this in cell E1 and then copy it down.

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C1;C1)
```

or

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C1,C1)
```

*depending on your country settings

What this does is put a 1  for each unique or first item and a counter number for all subsequent items. You could "advance" this with:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1;C1)>1;"<--";"")
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,C1)>1,"<--","")
```

The formula is then:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1;C1)>1;IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1;D1)=1;"<--";"");"")
```

Oh, b.t.w. In your example, you show 3 arrows, but the data between Cell C4 and Cell C5 is different! Therefore My formula only shows 2 arrows.

[image]

## AutoFormat

If you want to autoformat each marked row you format Cell A1 with the following:

Select: Formula
Enter: IF($E1="<--")
Create a newColour Scheme (e.g. MyYellow) and define the background for that scheme.

Now use the `format painter` to pick up the format of cell A1 and paste it over A1 to D8.

[image]

Comment: the arrows are something I added to show what I mean in the example, so I can't really use them in the real case

Comment: So the only thing you want is the highlighted yellow rows?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that... What I have are the numbers and letters (i.e. the arrows don't exist in the table); I want to know how many rows count as "duplicates" according to my criteria, and if possible highlight them.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?

Comment: Well this would identify duplicates with respect to field 3, but what happens if the rows are identical with respect to field 3 and 4? Those rows are not of interest.

Comment: Do I understand you right that you ONLY want the rows highlighted when the data in column C AND D TOGETHER is duplicated? In that situation you would ONLY get rows 8 and 10 highlighted.... Is this correct?

Comment: No, on the contrary: I want to have the rows that are duplicates on C and *not* duplicates on D. (The reason behind this whole mumbo jumbo is that those rows I am after are alternative solutions to the same problem, which should have essentially been in the same row listed after one another.)

Comment: I added the new formula: =IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1;C1)>1;IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1;D1)=1;"<--";"");"")